# how to substitute a variable in an array name?

Tags: arrays, tcl

Let's assume that thefilevalue_$thefile is an array that contains lists

```
foreach element [array names thefilevalue_$thefile] {
    puts "[lindex $thefilevalue_[subst $thefile]($element) 0]"
}
```

but it returns :

`can't read "thefilevalue_": no such variable`

i am in tcl 8.4 and i con't upgrade it.

how can i fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `set` and escape the parentheses, *e.g.*

```
array set thefilevalue_test {reds {orange red purple} blues {green blue purple}}
set thefile test
foreach element [array names thefilevalue_$thefile] {
    puts [lindex [set thefilevalue_$thefile\($element\)] 0]
}
```

This outputs for me (Tcl 8.0.5, and I can't upgrade either):

```
orange
green
```

Comment: Consider using `upvar 0 thefilevalue_$thefile ary` to give that array a shorter name. It makes the rest of the code much easier to write (e.g., `$ary($element)` instead of those gymnastics with `set`).

Comment: Also, in this case you could do `foreach {element content} [array get thefilevalue_$thefile] {...}`